# Tracking and circumventing Vagrant issues and bugs

Tags: vagrant

Every release of Vagrant for the past couples of years seems to either be broken or have major issues. For example, from the DC/OS Vagrant test lab environment we see their circumventing or avoiding Vagrant bugs:

```
case Vagrant::VERSION
when '1.9.1'
  require_relative 'patch/redhat_change_host_name_1.9.1'
  require_relative 'patch/redhat_configure_networks_1.9.1'
when '1.8.7'
  UI.error 'Unsupported Vagrant Version: 1.8.7', bold:true
  UI.error 'For more info, see https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7969'
  error_known_good_versions
when '1.8.6'
  require_relative 'patch/linux_network_interfaces_1.8.6'
when '1.8.5'
  UI.error 'Unsupported Vagrant Version: 1.8.5', bold:true
  UI.error 'For more info, see https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7610'
  error_known_good_versions
end
```

1.8.5 had the issue where people could not ssh into Linux instances and 1.8.7 had the issue where people on MacOS could not connect to Hashi's Vagrant cloud to download or update boxes. 1.9.0 also had the broken `.has_plugin?` API call that is unlisted above.

I have Vagrantfiles that I like to distribute for either portable lab or classroom environments to colleagues and students. I haven't been able to find a way to easily track the functioning versions of Vagrant, what the major issues are in the functioning versions, and how to circumvent them. I guess the closest thing would be to datamine the issue tracker on their Github and then parse and sort the output.

What would be the best way to deal with Vagrant's instability so I can provide circumvention in Vagrantfiles? Is there an easy way to track the issues?

I guess this also makes it difficult to deliver post-provisioned prebuilt boxes with Packer or `vagrant box` since different versions of Vagrant need different patches for their issues? I am guessing any circumvention that goes the route of prebuilt boxes (or just using them in general) will cause trouble because of Vagrant's instability.

Comment: Matt this is a really interesting question. I'm not sure how varied your users' environments are, but could you help reduce your problem by only supporting the last couple of releases? For example, today's latest is 1.9.3 and you could support 1.9.1+ by setting the [minimum Vagrant version](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/vagrant_version.html), then use your technique above for anything in 1.9.1, 1.9.2 or 1.9.3 that require special attention.

Comment: @BrianC I think limiting a version range would be helpful for reducing the amount of effort to fix issues with Vagrant, but I think it would almost be better to limit versions to non-recent releases where the issues have already been uncovered and are well-known. I am more concerned in this question with uncovering and tracking issues so that they can be compensated for and was planning a followup for an optimal method of compensating for issues.